# OCR google vision without cloud storage

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, pdf-generation, ocr, google-vision

i just learned about OCR google vision. 
I see it needs a pdf before it has been uploaded to Cloud Storage. can inputConfig be changed with other sources? for example from local storage maybe. thanks you.

[this is link i read about](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#vision_text_detection_pdf_gcs-nodejs)

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: i wanna use ocr google vision for pdf. i read https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#vision_text_detection_pdf_gcs-drest , to used cloud storage (gs:) for upload the pdf. i wanna to know, can i change the request in json body without gs: ? ex: using local path, or http://xxxxxxx.com

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation, the files have to be stored in GCS [Detect text in files (PDF/TIFF)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf):

> Currently PDF/TIFF document detection **is only** available for files stored in Cloud Storage buckets. Response JSON files are similarly
>   saved to a Cloud Storage bucket.

The `vision.types.GcsSource` takes a url (string) property:

> Google Cloud Storage URI for the input file. **This must only be a
>   Google Cloud Storage object**. Wildcards are not currently supported.

Also the function `vision.types.GcsDestination` takes a url (string) property:

> Google Cloud Storage URI where the results will be stored. Results
>   will be in JSON format and preceded by its corresponding input URI.
>   This field can either represent a single file, or a prefix for
>   multiple outputs. Prefixes must end in a /.
>
> Examples:
>
> File: gs://bucket-name/filename.json
>
> Prefix:gs://bucket-name/prefix/here/
>
> File: gs://bucket-name/prefix/here
>
> If multiple outputs, each response is still AnnotateFileResponse, each of
>   which contains some subset of the full list of AnnotateImageResponse.
>   Multiple outputs can happen if, for example, the output JSON is too
>   large and overflows into multiple sharded files.

[Package google.cloud.vision.v1p2beta1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1p2beta1#google.cloud.vision.v1p2beta1.GcsSource)